# I want to show modal position at the top (ng2semnatic template based modal)

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng2-semantic-ui

I am using template-based modal in my project, and modal position is in the middle of the page by default. Instead of this, I want to show the modal in top position.
[image]

Comment: can you share any piece of code which you have tried already?

Answer (score 1):

A modal is defined as 'position:absolute'(or 'fixed'), so also has a position in 'x' and 'y'. You can change this position, in it case in 'x' (top or bottom) in your css. Example:

```
.modal {position: absolute; top: 0}
```

or

```
.modal {position: fixed; top: 0}
```

Comment: This will update the position of all modals across the application. Is there a way to update the position of specific modals alone?